# Facebook and Twitter iframes crossing paths

Tags: facebook, iframe, twitter, facebook-iframe

I'm putting Tweet buttons and Facebook Like buttons on my site. They work fine in most areas but I have a modal popup (a popup that stays within the content window) that's causing some strange behavior. Basically on random page loads the facebook iframe will load twitter's content and visa versa. Some times there are two facebook buttons, some times there are two twitter buttons, and some times the facebook button will be in the place of the twitter button and visa versa. It only tends to happen in firefox and only on certain computers. My best guess is that the src streams are crossing paths but that doesn't seem to happen in other spots where the buttons are used.

I'd paste in the code, but it's the exact same code that everyone else on the planet is using for these buttons. Any thoughts?

UPDATE: 
A coworker of mine found a similar FireFox bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=431613

Their resolution was to set the iframe source to itself on page load. Still testing it, but unfortunately it only seems to be reproducible on live servers, which leads me to believe it might have something to do with Facebook and Twitter accessing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, I found this bug on Mozilla Bugs: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=431613

The solution to my issue was to move the Tweet button to the iframe version (before I was using their javascript Tweet button which dynamically loads the iframe when the page loads) and using setting the iframe.src to itself on page load (which is mentioned in the bug report on that bugzilla site).

Weird weird bug.